Faraday effect and relativity
The usual experiment demonstrating the Faraday effect uses a solenoid to create a magnetic field. It seems, however, it should be possible to get the effect using moving charged objects: Let's say we have a glass object along the z-axis and we shine polarized light into it along the z-axis. If we move a series of charged objects along the x-axis above the glass object, it will produce the faraday effect on the light, as there will be a magnetic field along the z-axis though the object.
Questions:

Will the setup explained above also produce the Faraday effect?
If we don't move the charged objects, but move the glass object along the x-axis instead, there will be no Faraday effect? (as there is no magnetic field.)
If we move with the glass object, the charged objects will in effect move the other way, will this produce the Faraday effect? (since there now is a magnetic field.)

This seems to be a contradiction, so what did I misunderstand?

"it should be possible to get the effect using moving charged objects" - moving charges produce magnetic fields, so I'm not sure how this is functionally different.

@controlgroup, what then about the apparent contradiction? Where does my reasoning go wrong?

I'm not sure that there is contradiction. In general I perceive a magnetic field if I perceive moving electric charges (or a magnetic monopole), unless I'm terribly mistaken.

@controlgroup, OK, so the anwers to the three questions are either yes, no, no or yes, yes, yes? In other words, is there a Faraday effect when the charges move relative to the background or relative to the glass? As far as I can tell, the answer cannot be yes, no, yes, as the two last situations are the same when it comes to observing the effect.

The Faraday effect needs a homogeneous magnetic bias field along the propagation vector $\mathbf k=k_\hat z$ of the plane wave. Bias field homogeneity is to be over the glass. I do not understand how you would produce such field with charges moving along the x-axis unless you mean a planar surface current moving uniformly distributed charges along $\hat x$. Note though that the Verdet factor for, say, TGG is $\approx 100rad/(Tm)$ so you need some serious magnetic intensity and implying large velocities to move a large amount of charges spread over the surface of a macroscopic object...

@hyportnex, OK, but given that we did have the needed charges and sensitive enough detectors, what would be the answers to the questions?

sans the typo that should read $\mathbf k = k\hat z$, I think I answered your question, that is, if the field you produce by moving charges is homogeneous along the propagation vector then you get the Faraday effect.

Answer 1: If the glass object thinks, that there is a magnetic field, then a Faraday effect is observed by anyone. Because then the glass object becomes asymmetric causing an asymmetry of propagation speed of differently polarized lights.
Answer 2: If observer observing a transparent object moving, thinks that the motion of the object causes there to be an asymmetry of length contractions of some things that move inside the object, then a Faraday effect is observed by the observer. Because then the object is asymmetric according to the observer. Which causes an asymmetry of propagation speed of differently polarized lights, according to the observer. Any observer observes a Faraday effect in this case, maybe not for the same reason as the observer.
Correction: The electric field of the static charges has an asymmetric effect on the positive charges moving to the right inside the object compared to the positive charges moving to the left inside the object. Because of different length contractions of things moving to the right vs. things moving to the left. A magnetic field would have exactly the same effect.
Answer 3: If the moving charges, cause otherwise non-polariced spins of electrons, or spins of molecules, or some orbital angular momentums, to become more polarized, then a Faraday effect is observed by anyone. Because then the object is asymmetric causing an asymmetry of propagation speed of differently polarized lights. This is the quantum mechanical answer.
